# Is there an equivalent of DEXP for complex*16 arguments in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran95

As stated in the question : Is there an equivalent of DEXP for complex*16 arguments in Fortran (90 and later)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`complex*16` isn't Fortran (90 or earlier or later).
If your data type is `complex(real64)` (or the non-standard `complex*16)` the standard generic `exp()` will select the corresponding precision and range.

Answer (score 2):

Where each part (Real and Imaginary) are 64 bits?

If you say COMPLEX(KIND=8) (intel) you get 64 bits for each the real and the imaginary. I'll need to see what gfortran gives...

It may best (I think most portable) to use ISO_C_BINDING and then 'see for yourself' :

```
PROGRAM ABC
USE ISO_C_BINDING
IMPLICIT NONE

COMPLEX(KIND=C_FLOAT_COMPLEX)  :: A
COMPLEX(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX)      :: B
COMPLEX(C_LONG_DOUBLE_COMPLEX) :: C

WRITE(*,*) SIZEOF(A)=',SIZEOF(A)
WRITE(*,*) SIZEOF(B)=',SIZEOF(B)
WRITE(*,*) SIZEOF(C)=',SIZEOF(C)

END PROGRAM ABC
```

Comment: If one wants 64-bit storage for each part of the complex, then `use iso_fortran_env, only : real64; complex(kind=real64) z; end` may be the best bet.  But this doesn't really address the question about how to exponentiate such a value.

Comment: I must say I have no idea. I code in Fortran for some months only and I learned from previous codes... So basically I'm declaring my complex variables as complex*16 without really knowing what is really done.

Comment: Complex*16 is a carry over from ibm360 fortran66. It means 8  bytes each for real and imaginary so where it works is same as complex(real64).  Real64 has the value 8 for the compilers mentioned.

Comment: How much precision to you need is the question @mwoua ... There is also LOG10, and generally one does not need a lot of precision on LOG or EXP values. The generic EXP covers DEXP and everything else... So I think you may want to look at just using EXP in place of DEXP. If it is a DOUBLE then you get DEXP, if it is a COMPLEX then you get CEXP. Why you would want to use DEXP on a COMPLEX instead of CEXP is questionable... and EXP works it out.

Answer (score 2):

Since Fortran 77 there is very little reason to use `DEXP()` directly, unless you are passing it as an argument.

In normal expressions (the most common use by far, probably your case) just use the generic `EXP()` for all exponentiations.

If you have the rare case where `DEXP()` is passed as an argument to a function then no, there is no equivalent and you have to write a wrapper function which calls the generic `EXP()`.

Answer (score 0):

zexp() and cdexp() in GNU Fortran.
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/EXP.html